# How to create a general JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, jackson

I need to create a general deserializer; in other words I don't know what the deserialised target class will be.

I have seen examples on the internet where by they create a deserializer such as `JsonDeserializer<Customer>` and then return a `new Customer(...)` at the end.  The problem is that I don't know what the return class will be.

I imagine I will need to use reflection to create an instance of the class and populate the field.  How can I do it from the deserialize method?

```
public class JsonApiDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        //Need to parse the JSON and return a new instance here
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have the JSON schema or a sample JSON?

Comment: yes, [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating)

Comment: May I ask *why* you need such a feature, instead of using default Jackson's deserializers?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner because jackson is unable to deserialize the JSON by default as the format is different to how Jackson would expect by default.

Comment: Is it an option to use MOXy, because with this you should be able serialize deserialize classes and annotate only the parameters you are interested in.

Comment: It might help if you showed an example of JSON structure, since it is not clear exactly how the structure differs, and why you feel a custom (de)serializer is needed. There are many features that could help change default behavior, and having to write fully custom deserializer is usually the last effort. For example, use of "any setters" and delegating-deserializers often allows doing conversions.

Comment: @StaxMan see the second comment.  I actually got it working anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some tests, I find @jax 's answer has a problem.

As @Staxman pointed out, `createContextual()` is called during construction of Deserializer, not in every process of deserialization. And the deserializer returned by `createContextual` will be cached by the Jackson library. So if your deserializer is used with more than 1 type(such as sub types of a common parent), it will throw out type mismatch exception, cause the targetClass property will be the last type cached by the Jackson library.

The correct solution should be:

```
public class JsonApiDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements
        ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<?> targetClass;

    public JsonApiDeserializer() {
    }

    public JsonApiDeserializer(Class<?> targetClass) {
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Object clazz = targetClass.newInstance();
        //Now I have an instance of the annotated class I can populate the fields via reflection
        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt,
            BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        //gets the class type of the annotated class
        targetClass = ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass();
        //this new JsonApiDeserializer will be cached
        return new JsonApiDeserializer(targetClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: newInstance() method is deprecated. Instead use getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance() Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there are only 2 cases you need to cater for, `Object` and `Object[]`, for which you can always deserialize to:

1. A Map
2. An array of Map

Something like this should work:

```
public class JsonApiDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = jp.getText();
        if (text.startsWith("{"))
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(text, Map.class);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(text, Map[].class);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Uncompiled and untested

Comment: But I need to deserialize to a java bean like Customer, Address etc.  This will not work for me.  I need some way of accessing the class and package name of the annotated entity.  I was thinking that this information might be contained in the DeserializationContext somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using ContextualDeserializer

```
public class JsonApiDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements
        ContextualDeserializer {

    private Class<?> targetClass;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Object clazz = targetClass.newInstance();

        //Now I have an instance of the annotated class I can populate the fields via reflection

        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt,
            BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        //gets the class type of the annotated class
        targetClass = ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass();
        return this;
    }

}
```

I am still a little unsure of why this works as I already have a `DeserializationContext ctxt` in the original deserialize method but it returns `null` when I do `ctxt.getContextualType()`.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Very interesting use of `getContextualType()`! :)
As to why -- it is ONLY set up when constructing `JsonDeserializer` instance, and not during actual deserialization. It is set by deserializer factory (or one of other handlers that delegate calls).

Comment: Another way to access type information would actually be to have a look at `property`; it has `JavaType` of the property. But it would not be passed for root-level values; and for some cases (elements of arrays, `List`s) it might not be exactly what you want. So it is probably better to use contextual type.

Comment: I don't know why no one upvote this answer. I need to write a general deserializer for all enum types in my project which all have a static method "getByCode" used to convert String to enum, and thanks to Java Enum Type (which can't inherit ) and Interface static method ( in Java 8 which can't be inherited by implementation), I need to know the target class but I can't get it by getContextualType of DeserializationContext in deserialize method. I've been googling all this afternoon and finally found this answer. It's elegant and concise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StaxMan How to get property info from DeserializationContext? And I assume you can only get that from createContextual, not deserialize method? Thanks.

Comment: @PickBoy difference is that `createContextual()` is called during construction of Deserializer, which conceptually happens outside of deserialization itself (no access to specific input), during which more information is passed. `deserialize()` on the other hand is during critical performance-sensitive path and is passed only what is needed, which does not include metadata used during construction of deserializer. So: in `createContextual()` you get `BeanProperty` that has all information. Except for "root values" not referenced via property.

Comment: I find jax's answer has a problem, so I post an answer with fix. Inspired by @StaxMan and jax. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the message structure in advance, you can use [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to easily generate `POJO`s from a given `JSON` string.

However, if your message format changes during runtime, and there is no other information for you to determine the type (for example, `header` information) you can deserialize into a `Map` and process the fields manually.

For example, with Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> userData = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Map.class);
```

Comment: I already have the beans mapped as hibernate entities so that tool will not work for me.  I am not interested in a translation intermediary step.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely got your question right but what you can do is to inspect the properties of the json inside the deserialiser doing something like:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
ObjectNode node = objectMapper.readTree(jp);
```

and then node.has("propertyName") so that you can create, setup and return your object and leave to the client of the deserialiser the responsibility of the cast.

you say " in other words I don't know what the deserialised target class will be. "

so I don't get if you can at least infer that, more info would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you know which classes **can** be deserialized in compile-time, but need to dynamically choose the right one in runtime depending on JSON contents I can suggest the following.

1. Add some classifier field into the JSON. This field will help your code know how to deal with the following data. As far as I can see, you already have the *"type"* field so that can be used.
2. Introduce a factory that will instantiate the specific classes depending on the input from JSON. For example, it may have the method like *Object create(string typeFromJson, Map data)*. Such factory may populate the newly-created object with the data as well.

If this is not the case and you don't know your required interfaces already, you are in trouble. It can be somewhat be worked around in C# with the use of *dynamic* keyword, but Java doesn't have such a feature yet.

Also, AFAIK, there is a way in Jackson to specify classes that need to be automatically deserialized and injected into *@Post* method calls in your REST resource class.

Comment: I agree that adding the java class name will solve this issue, however, I am guessing/hoping there is a better way.  I plan on releasing this to the public so don't want to apply unnecessary restrictions and noise to the data models of others if possible.

Comment: I see no other way, actually. If you need to need to bind the data from JSON to specific Java classes, you have to include some type information into JSON, one way or the other. You may also use some kind of duck typing to determine the target class on fields available, but that's something already implemented in Java libraries. Take a look on JAX-RS, for example.

Comment: Turns out you don't need the class information, see my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. But deserialize() method returns Object, I suppose you have to cast it to some specific domain type later then?

Comment: I actually didn't need to cast at all manually.  I think Jackson must do the cast automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: Still don't get it then... Can you please elaborate on how do you work with the returned Object later on?

Comment: They are REST requests coming in to a Spring @RestController.  So I have controller methods like `public JsonApiResponse save(@RequestBody Tutorial entity) { ... }`,   Jackson intercepts these requests before populating the @RequestBody.  Using the above method, the "entity" bean will contain the parsed JSON.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I initially thought you intended to use that deserializer directly. Thanks for clarification!