# Deserialization of subclasses without type information

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class representing kinds of finite-domain values (similar to enums):

```
public abstract class AbstractEnum {
    private String id;
    // ...
}
```

and concrete classes `EnumA, EnumB` extending `AbstractEnum`.
A business object might look like

```
public class Obj {
    private EnumA a;
    private EnumB b;
    // ...
}
```

The instances of `EnumA, EnumB` are managed by a factory. When deserializing an `Obj`, I would like to call the factory instead of the constructors. The concrete type (`EnumA` or `EnumB`) cannot be inferred from the JSON representation of the enum values because they only contain their ID, but is inferred from the corresponding property type in `Obj`.

I tried using `@JsonCreator` or `@JsonDeserialize` (with converter) on `AbstractEnum`, but the property type doesn't seem to be made available to the creator/converter. It seems that I have to either use `@JsonTypeInfo` to serialize extra type information (which seems redundant), or define a creator/converter for each concrete `AbstractEnum` subclass, of which there are many more than just two.
Is there another way?

**Edit**: Instances of `EnumA` can have the same IDs as instances of `EnumB`, therefore the ID cannot be used to deduce the type.

Comment: You should implement a custom `JsonDeserializer` for `AbstractEnum`. In it you can use your factory.

Comment: Because `EnumA` and `EnumB` have their own variable name in `Obj`, then the JSON serialization should be able to tell if the field `a` and field `b` are present or not.  Basically field name (aka the variable name) will distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `ContextualDeserializer` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32587190/1829158): in `createContextual()` I grab the concrete class, and in `deserialize()` I call my factory to get an instance based on `targetClass` and the ID.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that you can use field name to distinguish the type, and not have to rely on a factory or anything else.  I am assuming here that the field named `a` will always refer to type `EnumA` and so on.  Below is some test code that uses your code and tries to show that field name alone might do the trick.

```
public class SpikeJson {

    public static abstract class AbstractEnum {

        private final String id;

        protected AbstractEnum(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "AbstractEnum{" + "id=" + id + '}';
        }

    }

    public static class EnumA extends AbstractEnum {

        public EnumA() {
            super("enuma");
        }

    }

    public static class EnumB extends AbstractEnum {

        public EnumB() {
            super("enumb");
        }

    }

    public static class EnumC extends AbstractEnum {

        public EnumC() {
            super("enumc");
        }

    }

    public static class Obj {

        @JsonProperty
        private EnumA a;
        @JsonProperty
        private EnumB b;
        @JsonProperty
        private EnumC c;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Obj{" + "a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + '}';
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //{
        //  "a": {},
        //  "b": null
        //}
        String json = "{\n"
                + " \"a\": {},\n"
                + " \"b\": null\n"
                + "}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Obj obj = om.readValue(json, Obj.class);
        System.out.println("obj = " + obj);

    }

}
```

The output of this code is

> obj = Obj{a=AbstractEnum{id=enuma}, b=null, c=null}

which shows that the JSON was properly deserialized.

Comment: Yes, deserializing `Obj` works, but the standard deserialization creates new instances of the enum classes, while I need to ensure that there is at most one instance for every combination of enum class and ID. I solved it using `ContextualDeserializer`, see my answer.